# deleting books from ibooks

Tags: books

I've deleted several books from ibooks but each time I open the app, those books are there and I have to delete them again.  I've gone through this process probably 10 times.

Comment: [iBooks for Mac: Delete books from your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22584?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Is it possible to COMPLETELY delete a Book from my purchased books?](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/132778)